# Optimize polars csv load to prevent OOM crash

Tags: jupyter, limit, ram, python-polars

I have not been able to get .sink_parquet() to work with csv + aggregations/expressions yet:

```
df = pl.scan_csv('file.csv')
(df
 .with_columns(pl.col('col_1').str.split(', '))
 .explode('col_1')
 .sink_parquet('file.parquet')
)
```

I get the "sink_parquet not yet supported in standard engine. Use 'collect().write_parquet()'" error, but I still exceed RAM and crash the notebook when I attempt to process large amounts of data with .collect(streaming=True).write_parquet('file.parquet')

Is it possible to set a limit for the amount of RAM Polars uses so I don't keep crashing my jupyter env? At least until .sink_parquet() is available?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be an issue on github and not on stackoverflow

Comment: There's a 'feature' label at [the Polars Github Issues page](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues) for tagging posts with 'New feature or request'.

Comment: @0x26res I don't think they're asking for a feature.  I think they're asking if there's a way to do that now.

Comment: This is my first time posting, but I thought I'd read in their New Feature/Request that they wanted to see the question here before they took it as a request.

Comment: `explode` is not yet supported in our streaming engine. But I don't think it is complicated for us to support that. Can you open a feature request for this?

Edit: I made one: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/7334

Answer (score 0):

There's not a one thing you can do to guarantee you never crash your notebook.

There are things you can do to avoid crashing it when working with data that is bigger than memory.

The first thing to do is look at the [docs](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.scan_csv.html) and notice that there's a `low_memory` parameter that you can set in `scan_csv`.  I've never used it and I definitely don't know your data so I have no way of knowing if that, alone, will solve your issue.

If that doesn't work then the thing to do would be to segment the data.

Perhaps you do something like:

```
df = pl.scan_csv('file.csv', low_memory=True)
uniqcol1=df.select(pl.col('col_1').unique()).collect().to_series()
for some_value in uniqcol1:
    df.filter(pl.col('col_1')==some_value) \
         .with_columns(pl.col('col_1').str.split(', ')) \
         .explode('col_1') \
         .collect().write_parquet(f"file{some_value}.parquet")
```

If that doesn't work then you can use some combination of `n_rows`, `row_count_name`, and `row_count_offset` in `scan_csv` to ensure you're not loading too much data at once but it'd be a for loop with some number of rows at a time.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that as well as the predicate_pushdown and a couple other options, none of them really alleviated things. Though just got confirmation that the `unique` is hard to do streaming, but if I rewrite things as a groupby, it should stream. They did say they'd work on implementing a streaming `explode`. Thanks for your help!